# Force Visual Studio to find from cursor

Tags: visual-studio

Just upgraded to VS 2019... and by default (in this and previous versions)... if I search within a document, every subsequent search I make for the same text searches relative to the previous find result... not where I reposition the cursor. I know it is possible to reset the search by moving the cursor... but how? The setting is frustratingly elusive... and not being able to rely on finding the first result after a specific point without first searching for something else, then what you actually want to find, is doubly frustrating! :-(

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what changed... but now it is behaving as expected. If anyone has an explanation of what controls the behaviour of the find function, I'd really like to hear it - I remember this tripping me up last time I upgraded Visual Studio.

Comment: I had a similar experience using, was it *Visual Studio* 97(?) or maybe earlier, where I had a similar way of searching for things and my way was against the grain (I've forgotten the specifics, but remember the pain). so I sympathize for I was in your situation.... :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can select a piece of text and search in the selection. It will continue after outside the selection.
I agree, starting search from the currentl cursor location would be much more intuitive and comfortable.

Answer (score -2):

In this situation, unable to fight design, it might be better served to take a different way of looking/thinking and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to do a "find all" into a search results dialog. Then *instead* move around the Find Locations as needed.

Otherwise you would need to cancel the initial search and restart the search after moving the cursor to the new location.

Comment: That's a deeply unsatisfying answer. And having just upgraded to the latest available version of VS2019... it has happened again!!! I am so used to typing "CTRL-HOME", searching for a particular class to get my starting point, then searching from that point for something I know to be in that class... but this behaviour takes me to random other places in the file - so frustrating!!